# Jacobi determinant for high-dimensional sphere inversion

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, determinant

I need to find the Jacobi determinant for the unit sphere inversion in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the map given by $f(x) = \frac x {|x|^2}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. The main problem is to figure out the determinant of the following matrix (when $\xi = f(x)$):
$$\frac 1 {|\xi|^{4n}}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
|\xi|^2 - 2\xi_1^2 & -2\xi_1\xi_2 &\ldots& -2\xi_1\xi_n\\
-2\xi_2\xi_1 & |\xi|^2 - 2\xi_2^2 & \ldots& -2\xi_2\xi_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
-2\xi_n\xi_1 & \ldots & -2\xi_n\xi_{n-1} & |\xi|^2 - 2\xi_n^2
\end{array}\right]$$
Direct computation for low dimensions suggests that the result is $-\frac 1 {|\xi|^{2n}}$, but the recursive formula for n-th dimension seems terribly complicated, and involves all smaller dimensions. Is there a relatively simple way to solve this problem?

Comment: See my answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667091/is-line-element-mathematically-rigorous.

Comment: Thank you! After all it is very intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the Jacobian is equal to $-1$ on the unit sphere. Indeed, consider an orthonormal basis at a point of the unit sphere where one of basis vectors is normal to the sphere. Under inversion, the normal flips its sign while  the rest remain as they were: hence, the Jacobian matrix has eigenvalues $-1,1,1,\dots,1$.

Now take any $x_0$ with $|x_0|=r>0$. Observe that for all $x$,
$$
f(x) = r^{-1}f(r^{-1} x)
$$
Taking the Jacobian on both sides yields
$$
J_f(x) = r^{-n}J_f(r^{-1} x)r^{-n} = -r^{-2n}
$$