# d3x - Cartesian to Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, volume

Given is $d^3x = dxdydz$ and I need to convert it to cylindrical coordinates (given through: $x = r\cos\varphi$  and $y = r\sin\varphi$).

The expected result is: **$(dz)(dr)(r)(d\varphi)$** and I cannot seem to get it right.

This is what I am doing:

$dz = dz$
$dy = \frac{dy}{d\varphi} d\varphi = r \cos\varphi d\varphi = \frac{dy}{dr} = \sin\varphi dr$
$dx = \frac{dx}{d\varphi} d\varphi = - r \sin\varphi d\varphi = \frac{dx}{dr} dr = \cos\varphi dr$

But I can't see how to create the expected solution from this.

Answer (score 1):

The colored area under the picture is the unit area in polar coordinates.

$\Delta A = (\pi.(r+ \Delta r)^2 - \pi(r)^2). \frac{\Delta \theta}{2\pi}$

$\Delta A = \frac{(2r\Delta r + {\Delta r}^2).\Delta\theta}{2}$

Since we assume $(\Delta r)^2$ is negligable because of the square, we have

$\Delta A = r\Delta r\Delta\theta$

The $dz$ contribution is trivial.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobian of $(r,\phi,z)\mapsto (r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi,z)$ is
$$
\left|\matrix{
  \cos\phi &  \sin\phi & 0\cr
-r\sin\phi & r\cos\phi & 0\cr
      0    &      0    & 1
}\right| = r,
$$
so the volume element is $r\,dr\,d\phi\,dz$.

Comment: But do you have an idea what is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive, *what*  is your result?

Comment: The three lines I posted. Shouldn't they be a possible way to find the solution as well?

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive, the $d\cdots$ notation can be misleading. See the question and my answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667091/is-line-element-mathematically-rigorous/667126#667126.